# generate two different view with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I wonder if it is possible to view 2 generated with different currency: 
View 1: admins for model => admin 
view 2: users to model user

thanks

Comment: Do you have two different logins or one?

Comment: I have two different connection